# How to find whether a table has a given date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-comparison

I want to find out whether a table has rows within the range of dates passed to the query. The following is the data in `MYTABLE`. I am using SQL Server

```
DISPLAY_START_DATE      DISPLAY_END_DATE
2022-02-02 00:00:00.000     2022-02-28 00:00:00.000
2022-02-02 00:00:00.000     2022-02-06 10:34:01.653
2022-02-01 00:00:00.000     2022-02-17 00:00:00.000
2022-02-07 00:00:00.000     2022-02-25 00:00:00.000
```

The following is my query

```
DECLARE @startdate AS datetime ='2022-02-01' 
DECLARE @enddate AS datetime ='2022-02-10'
SELECT * from MYTABLE mt
WHERE 
(mt.DISPLAY_START_DATE = @startdate and  mt.DISPLAY_END_DATE = @enddate)    OR
(mt.DISPLAY_START_DATE < @startdate and  mt.DISPLAY_END_DATE > @enddate)    OR
(mt.DISPLAY_START_DATE < @startdate and  mt.DISPLAY_END_DATE < @enddate)    OR
(mt.DISPLAY_START_DATE < @startdate and  mt.DISPLAY_END_DATE < @enddate and  
    mt.DISPLAY_END_DATE > @startdate)   OR
(mt.DISPLAY_START_DATE > @startdate and  mt.DISPLAY_END_DATE < @enddate) OR
(mt.DISPLAY_START_DATE > @startdate and mt.DISPLAY_START_DATE < @enddate and 
    mt.DISPLAY_END_DATE < @enddate)
```

This pulls only the second row corresponding to the following data

```
DISPLAY_START_DATE      DISPLAY_END_DATE
2022-02-02 00:00:00.000     2022-02-06 10:34:01.653
```

Comment: Please mention your desired output for better understanding.

Comment: Define precisely what "in the range means". I suggest you draw an actual time line, add the begin and end points for any given datetime range from your table as a sample and then draw the range above your time line for your begin and end parameters to **visually see** how they compare. You might be looking for "completely contained within", "ends within but can start at any time", etc. Serg's suggestion should likely do what you want - but the requirements are very much undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select all the rows having both the dates within given range you can try below query:

```
DECLARE @startdate AS datetime ='2022-02-01' 
DECLARE @enddate AS datetime ='2022-02-10'

SELECT * from MYTABLE mt
WHERE 
(mt.DISPLAY_START_DATE between @startdate and @enddate and mt.DISPLAY_END_DATE between @startdate and @enddate)
```

Or if you want a where condition to select all the rows from the table which have fully or partially in the range

```
SELECT * from MYTABLE mt
WHERE 
(mt.DISPLAY_START_DATE between @startdate and @enddate and mt.DISPLAY_END_DATE between @startdate and @enddate) or
(mt.DISPLAY_START_DATE <=@startdate and mt.DISPLAY_END_DATE >=@enddate) or
(mt.DISPLAY_START_DATE <=@startdate and mt.DISPLAY_END_DATE between @startdate and @enddate) or
(mt.DISPLAY_START_DATE between @startdate and @enddate  and mt.DISPLAY_END_DATE >=@enddate)
```

Comment: Thanks Kazi. I have used your second solution. It worked perfectly!

Comment: You are mostwelcome. Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

Two intervals intersection condition is each interval must start before the other ends:

```
..
WHERE mt.DISPLAY_START_DATE <= @enddate AND @startdate <= mt.DISPLAY_END_DATE
```